# Display data from Firebase in a TextView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textview

I am trying to display a string from Firebase to a textview. My app keeps crashing when clicking on the `get data` button. When I debug my codes, it shows this error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert an object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.example.dijap537.firebasedatabase.Students

And this is the line that causes the error

`name2.setText(students.getStudentName());`

Here is how I add the data strings `(Id, studentName, studentClass)`.

Question, are those data strings stored as an array?

```
public void addStudents() {
    String studentName = name.getText().toString();
    String studentClass = class_.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(studentName)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(studentClass)) {

        String id = "1";//databaseReference.push().getKey(); //get Unique ID

        final Students students = new Students(id,studentName,studentClass); //send the data (send ID NAME AND CLASS)

        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(students); //WRITE DATA TO FIREBASE

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        name.setText("");
        class_.setText("");
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Type The Students Name or Class",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the `Students.java` in case anyone needs to see it.

```
public class Students {
    private String studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String StudentClass;

    public Students(String studentName1) { }

    public Students(String studentId, String studentName, String studentClass) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.StudentClass = studentClass;
    }

    public String getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentClass() {
        return StudentClass;
    }
}
```

And here is how I am trying to retrieve the data. Note, I am only trying to get the `studentName` string. And this is where the app has the error mentioned above. I know now it is because I am trying to display an array with a `textView`, But still, I only want to retrieve and display the `studentName` string. What is the correct way to do that if it is possible?

```
public void getStudents() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Students students = dataSnapshot.getValue(Students.class);
            name2.setText(students.getStudentName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Firebase Structure:[image]

Comment: I don't think that exception matches the line of code that you're showing.  It's probably this one: `Students students = dataSnapshot.getValue(Students.class);`

Comment: Does not solve the problem but class names should always be singular, so maybe you should change "Students" to "Student" and your field "StudentClass"should be in lower case like "studentClassNr" or something like this